# How do I type the ^ in Raspberry terminal

Tags: raspbian

How do I type a `^` in Raspberry Pi's Terminal so that I can select `Y` as an answer for saving a change?

Comment: `^` is just bash script shorthand for the Ctrl key. Someone decided that the space saved compared to `Ctrl X` was worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's shift 6 on my keyboard.

Could you give some context?  It doesn't sound like a key to be used to indicate "Y".

Comment: In the terminal window in on a Raspberry Pi4 desktop, at the very bottom of the window are options such as ^Y or ^N, and afternoon typing a line to modify (eg) DNS servers), I’m asked if I want to save.  I need to be able to say Yes!

Comment: Should say “after” and not “afternoon”

Comment: I’ve tried that, and get nothing - I “think” I need some sort of release to get to the very bottom of the window.

Comment: that is the CTRL key ... press CTRL-y .... it could also mean *default* ... pressing the *enter* key selects the default

Comment: Perhaps my keyboard is wonky. Ctrl-x works, as does curl-c, but ctrl-y does nothing, nor does esc times two

Answer (score 1):

That caret symbol means <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd>.